# DIG domain ns couldn't be reached

Tags: debian, debian-jessie, dig

I installed Powerdns with Debian Jessie and i added NS record and other DNS records in PowerAdmin when i test the record added with dig it gives  no servers could be reached, i added both name servers in my registrar and also in Powerdns SOA records and NS records and A records for both NS for this domain

```
    dig mediapal.biz NS

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u6-Debian <<>> mediapal.biz NS
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, your zone seems to have two declared nameservers, according to the glue records:

```
[me@risby personal]$ dig ns mediapal.biz @a.gtld.biz.
[...]
mediapal.biz.           7200    IN      NS      NS2.mediapal.biz.
mediapal.biz.           7200    IN      NS      NS1.mediapal.biz.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
NS1.mediapal.biz.       7200    IN      A       69.197.146.43
NS2.mediapal.biz.       7200    IN      A       69.197.146.44
```

Neither of these nameservers seems very responsive:

```
[me@risby personal]$ dig soa mediapal.biz @69.197.146.43
[...]
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
[me@risby personal]$ dig soa mediapal.biz @69.197.146.44
[...]
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

So either your nameservers aren't serving that zone to general requestors, or they're behind a firewall that's not properly configured, or something else is wrong: from outside, it's impossible to say more.  But if you're sure those nameservers are up and accessible, I'd urge you to (a) say so, **and** (b) show us some evidence.

And *thank you* for not redacting the domain; these questions are nigh-impossible from people who insist on not telling us the domain in question.

Comment: i added all my records inside PowerAdmin for more info

Comment: I have no idea what PowerAdmin is; I'm guessing some kind of web control panel for DNS (in which case be careful, many web control panel questions are *prima facie* off-topic for ServerFault).  More to the point, what you've shown addresses none of my potential issues.  Do you know that either of those nameservers is actually running a name server?  How do you know this?  Are they behind a firewall (either an appliance, or `iptables`, or both)?

Comment: Its DNS control panel for PowerDNS, my /etc/resolv.conf file contain both of them ...43 and ...44. there is no tables in firewall

Comment: Yes, I can read that, thanks; and it agrees with your glue records.  **But those two servers, .43 and .44**: are they serving the zone to the world at large?  If you think they are, show us why you think that.  Are those two servers yours (do you control them)?  If not, what makes you think they're functional servers for your zone?

Comment: Yes i have full control of the server , this is two interfaces i added them to the server and want to use them as nameserver i added them to the registrar and i add also to poweradmin

Comment: Great.  What makes you think the server is serving your zone?  What happens on that server when you do, say, `dig soa mediapal.biz @69.197.146.43`?

Comment: it gives this ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
its already added in powerdns, should i add 69.197.146.43 and 69.197.146.44 in /etc/resolv.conf?? im looking to use a private nameserver..

Comment: I see absolutely no reason to believe that you have a working nameserver on this server, which owns the .43 and .44 addresses.  Do you?

Comment: i added soa record in poweradmin whyit didnt resolve?

Comment: **Your nameserver isn't serving any names to anyone** from what I can tell, from the tests you have done.  What some web application tells you is happening does not represent reality.  **You need to start paying more attention to what reality tells you, and less to what your web browser tells you.**